Is Spring 4.2.4 Compatible with Keycloak Spring Security Adapter? What Dependencies Are Required?
I'm currently working on a project using Spring 4.2.4 and I'm considering integrating Keycloak for security management.
Is Spring 4.2.4 compatible with the Keycloak Spring Security Adapter?
What specific dependencies do I need to include in my pom.xml to set up Keycloak with this version of Spring?
Any guidance or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Are you seriously expecting some guidance for using a Spring version almost 10 years old, without Boot apparently with something designed with Spring Boot, and itself deprecated years ago (Spring 4.2.4 was released on Dec 17, 2015, and Keycloak Boot adapters in early 2022)? If you're concerned with security, start by using current versions of the frameworks you use.

ok thank you appreciated

Start there: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-keycloak
